# How can I go back to initial login page from one of the navigation controller in a tab bar controller correctly?

Tags: ios, swift

I now have a login page, and if I sign in successfully it will show the tab bar controller. And in the tab bar controller there are five navigation controllers, and in one of the navigation controller there will a log out button. I want to ask how do I go back to the login page with this button correctly ? I think I should dismiss all views in the tab bar when I go back to the initial page ( Is this right?) . But I have no idea how to do it programmatically with swift, which function should I use? Someone suggest unwind segue,but I don't know if it will dismiss all the five views in the tab bar when I come back to login page.

Comment: the LoginViewController is outside the TabbarViewController? So you have LoginVC -> TabVC[index] -> NavC -> VC ? If you have everything done via storyboard please post a screenshot of it.

Comment: If your LoginVC is your initial root viewcontroller and presents you TabVC, then the following should work: UIApplication.shared.keyWindow?.rootViewController?.dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)